# Inputs sized using percentages not rendering correctly in Webkit

Tags: css, forms, osx-mavericks

I've been tasked with an odd assignment.

We have a png image of a form that we're overlaying HTML form elements on top of. Since our users are on a variety of devices, I've had to design it so the form resizes to stay at 95% of browser width. Thus, all the form elements are positioned and sized using percentages (yes, I know this is ugly, but it works).

I've noticed what I'm perceiving as a bug and wondering if anybody else has encountered this: on Webkit browsers, on Mavericks only, and it's only sporadically, when the page loads, the fields appear blank. They have values (as can be demonstrated by firing a jQuery .val() command), but they're just not visible. Upon resizing the window or selecting a field, the value magically appears.

This is very confusing to me, and it's so odd that it's such an isolated variety of factors.

Anybody else able to duplicate, or has run into this, and any idea of how I can resolve this? I've actually been able to do a "hacky-fix" where, on page load, I do a resize of my main content div from 95% to 95.01%, and that redraw fixes everything, but I don't like such a hack.

Comment: Can you add your HTML and CSS with the image in a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry Mathias, it's rather proprietary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the exact same issue and we've found that the root cause is a css transition we were using to show the page from alpha 0 to 100. So as soon as we removed that transition all the fields were shown correctly. I liked you hack BTW

Comment: You're correct, it was some conflict with the rendering while a CSS transition took place. Replacing the CSS transition with a jQuery transition has resolved it perfectly.